# RPI4 corrupted SD or more sensitive to issues than RPI3?

Tags: sd-card, archlinux, pi-4, corrupt

I've had an RPI4 running ArchLinuxArm for about 2 months without making any changes to it. Yesterday, I noticed it wasn't online so I did some troubleshooting.

- The bootloader rescue worked as intended
- A clean Raspbian on a different SD booted fine (should rule out damaged Pi)
- It's SD boots fine on a RPI3 and can be mounted without issues on other systems (should rule out damaged SD)

So the RPI4 gets stuck on the rainbow screen with four green led flashes at boot and then just solid red if using it's Arch installation. Could it be that the RPI4 is more sensitive to issues on SD cards than the RPI3 or does someone have any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: I gggole for Rpi4B and green LED blink 4 times and only found the following seems related. (1) https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=346051
(2) https://libreelec.tv/2019/06/libreelec-9-2-alpha1-rpi4b/

Comment: See [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151) - but I would just restore from my backup.

Comment: Check the date of stuff in the boot partition to see when it was last replaced.

Comment: I wouldn't rule out the SD card. The Pi4 can get hotter than the Pi3 and maybe your card cannot take that heat.